# Running SQL from file MySQL - User Input?

Tags: mysql, database, command-line, user-input

I'm running MySQL from the command line and executing SQL stored in files. What I'm trying to do, is prompt the user to enter input so that I can include this in the SQL script? Is there a way to do this with MySQL?

Many thanks,
James

Comment: Who is supposed to be that user and what interface they use? a console?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply. Yes it's the user and through a console - all users are trusted so security is not an issue here.

Comment: This is an operating system issue. For example, you have to write a bash script which reads the user input and executes the sql command with this input. So which operating system are you using?

Comment: Hi - thanks for your input! I'm running Mac OS X - Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute sql script from the file try this:

```
mysql -u USER -p -D DATABASE < input_filename.sql
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for that! I've got it running SQL from files (I'm using source <path>) but I'm looking for a way to get user input into the script.